# Need team foundation server / system 2012 Server - AD

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 service pack 1 .

For the installation of team foundation server/system 2012 requires AD ??

tnx ;)

Answer (score 2):

The true answer is "it depends".
For a very small group, if can fit everything on a single server, you don't need AD.
As soon as the system grows and you have multiple machines and users, you must have AD, at least for your mental health.
If you think, that you will need to grow someday, then start adopting AD immediately (and consider redundancy) as converting TFS accounts later is a painful job.